# Unable to get object from JSON from iTunes API

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am building a music application using angular and for data I am using Apple iTunes API. When I am fetching JSON results I am unable to get object properties.

Below is the data returned by itune API:

[data returned from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmo46.png)

I can render some properties like category, id, title etc. But unable to render properties which have **im:** before their name like `im:artist`, `im:name` etc.

This is how I am rendering data in html component:

```
// This Works  
<div *ngFor="let track of tracks">{{track.title.label}}</div>

// This does not work 
<div *ngFor="let track of tracks">{{track.im:name.label}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<div *ngFor="let track of tracks">{{track['im:name'].label}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems bad json of tracks, but you can achieve like below ways.

1. If you believe there is always object `track.im:name.label` then you can below trick

   ```
   <div *ngFor="let track of tracks">{{track["im:name"].label}}</div>
   ```
2. Another way

   ```
   <div *ngFor="let track of tracks">{{getLabel(track)}}</div>

   getLabel(task){
     if(task["im:name"] && task["im:name"].label){
       return task["im:name"].label
     } else {
       return ""
     }
   }
   ```